# Access variables of an array elements using perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access a specific variable member in the array in perl.

```
my $array = [];
@{$array} = (
             { 'family'  => "abc", 
               'roles'   => {},
             },
             { 'family'  => "def", 
               'roles'   => {
                              'member'=>["1234"],
                            },
             },
            );
```

I tried to access the values using

```
foreach (@{$array}){
   print " $_->{'family'} \n"; 
   #This is printing the family value 
}
```

Could someone explain to me how i could access the member field.i tried using $_->roles->{'member'} but this doesn't seem to work. any inputs here would be of great help.

I get the below output..i am not getting any error.

Hash(0x268d35)->roles->{'memeber'}

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: `$_->{'roles'}{'member'}` among other ways.

Comment: Hi Shawn, i tried it but it doesnt work, i get ARRAY(0x28b38cc)

Comment: `$_->{roles}->{member}` is an array ref, so you'll need to de-reference it with `@{ ... }`. Otherwise it'll get again stringified, hence `ARRAY(...)`.

Comment: May I point you to [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#The-Rest)? "If you try to use a reference like a string, you get strings like `ARRAY(0x80f5dec)`   or  `HASH(0x826afc0)`"

Comment: thank you. will refer to this document.

Comment: also http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```perl
# hash ref, key 'family' pointing to scalar
print $_->{family}, "\n";
# hash ref, key 'roles' pointing to hash ref,
#    key 'members' pointing to array ref 
print @{ $_->{roles}->{member} }, "\n";
```

Your hash reference got interpolated into a string, hence the `HASH(...)`.

Complete code example based on your code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $array = [
    {
        family => "abc",
        roles  => {},
    },
    {
        family => "def",
        roles  => {
            member => ["1234"],
        },
    },
];

for my $hash_ref (@{ $array }) {
    print "family ", $hash_ref->{family}, "\n";
    while (my($key, $value) = each %{ $hash_ref->{roles} }) {
        print "role '${key}' @{ $value }\n";
    }
}

exit 0;
```

Test run

```
$ perl dummy.pl
family abc
family def
role 'member' 1234
```

Comment: :Thank you. i tried this, for this i get ARRAY(0xxxxxxxx).I am not getting the value in member field. Is there anything i am missing here.

Comment: See the updated full code example with test run. As you can see it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan, this works. Will read the perlreftut you sent.